Symmetry generated from order
What's missing in the 4th grid? The answer is an 8-letter word. Explain your reasoning.



I haven't told you what kind of order ofc but here's a hint...

 Don't focus on the figures. In other words - it's the process that leads to the figures that's important.

Stronger hint

 Connect in order of... (something)

Been some days now so here's a strong hint

 point to point "d"


To save you some time.... they're not dependant on each other, however they are in correct order....

Is the question asking what's missing in the 4th grid, or is the 4th grid meant to be empty?

@DanDan面 Yes, what's missing in the 4th grid. I'll clarify that.

Added a stronger hint. Last hint for some days. Hopefully someone can see what's going on.

The missing object is

 an OCTAGRAM (an 8-pointed star).

 There are only five possible distances you can measure on a 3x3 grid. In order from smallest to largest they are: 1 unit (adjacent points), $\sqrt{2}$ units (diagonally touching points), 2 units (points 2 apart in the same row/column), $\sqrt{5}$ units (points a knight's move apart), and $2\sqrt{2}$ (opposite corners).

 Each picture in this sequence connects all possible pairs of points with that distance. The fourth picture should therefore connect all points that are a knight's move apart, which forms an 8-pointed star:




Well that went faster than expected :D Great job!

My answer:

 Dihedral

Reasoning:

 The symmetry group of each object is the dihedral group of order 8.


Nice attempt, but this is not it. It's not based of some knowledge/known groups.

Should I delete this answer?

It's completely fine if you leave it, but you do as you like ofc
